# Pre-checked RoR builds with Git and Hudson?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

On .NET projects, I've used TeamCity and Subversion to run [pre-checked builds](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/features/delayed_commit.html).

For those unfamiliar with pre-checked builds, the idea is that when you commit, a build is run with your changeset against trunk.

If that build passes, *then* your changeset is applied to trunk.  If it doesn't pass, you're notified and can try again.

That way, builds from trunk should always be green, and no-one else on the team is interrupted by build breakage.

My question is: has anyone achieved a similar workflow on a Ruby on Rails project, using Git and Jenkins (a.k.a. Hudson)?  If so, could you please share some hints / tips / documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at a Jenkins/Gerrit combination. Gerrit is a code review system that you can setup so it will not push your commit to master unless your commit is approved. You can set it up so that Jenkins first has to approve it.

We are starting to use it for a C++ project where Jenkins first tries to build the patch, if it succeeds it is pushed to the main repo. This also doesn't stall git on the client side.

- http://jenkins-ci.org/
- https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger

Answer (score 0):

To truely do this, you want to use a Git pre-receive hook. An excellent one (which runs PHP tests when code has been pushed) is detailed in: [a blog post on codeutopia.net](http://codeutopia.net/blog/2011/06/30/how-to-automatically-run-unit-tests-from-a-git-push/)

However, the last sentence of the entry states:

> it will cause the git push to be delayed until its completion.

Which is no fun if your test suite takes minutes to run, and *seriously annoying* when it takes 10 or 20 minutes (because `git` on the dev's machine will sit there and wait and not let go until the pre-receive hook exits).

Now, you may be able to write some sort of Hudson script to revert the failing commit when a build breaks. A former team experimented with such an idea, but never implemented it.